# Handlebars {{#each}} helper displaying wrong amount of values that i get from Mongoose.model.find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

When I try to use `{{#each}}` on my `list.handlebars`, it shows 2 contents inside the `{{#each}}` before it shows my content-filled data, I'm trying to figure out whats going on but from all I've been studying, I've seen no solution for this.

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

#### app.js (main code):

```js
app.get("/lista/:arvores", (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.arvores === "arvoresnativas") {
        db.nativas.find().then((dataArvoresNativas) => {
            dataArvoresNativas.forEach((findArvoresNativas) => {
                console.log(findArvoresNativas);
                res.render("lista.handlebars",
                    {
                        findArvNativas: findArvoresNativas,
                        strArv: stringArvoresNativas,
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    }
});
```

#### list.handlebars

```
<h1>Lista de {{strArv}}</h1>

{{#each findArvNativas}}
    <h2>Nome: {{nome}}</h2>
    <h2>Nome científico: {{nomecientifico}}</h2>
    <h2>Ordem: {{ordem}}</h2>
    <h2>Origem: {{origem}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

And here's the mongo.js, the mongoose connection where I export the `Moongoose.model()` for native and exotic species of trees on my country (I'm Brazilian, sorry for the var names, I hope someone could understand my code anyways):

#### mongo.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost/mongodatabase", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Conectado ao MongoDB!"))
    .catch((error) => console.log("Erro ao tentar se conectar ao MongoDB: " + error));

const arvores = mongoose.Schema({
    nome: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },

    nomecientifico: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },

    ordem: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },

    origem: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
});

const arvoresnativas = mongoose.model("arvoresnativas", arvores);
const arvoresexoticas = mongoose.model("arvoresexoticas", arvores);

module.exports = {
    nativas: arvoresnativas,
    exoticas: arvoresexoticas,
};
```

When I go to http://localhost:3031/lista/arvoresnativas, thats my output:

[image: HTML rendering]

but looks what the mongo query shows when I do `db.arvoresnativas.find()`:

[image: Log]

I tried to drop the table and defines it again, also I tried almost everything but I'm a beginner, I couldn't do much more than what I could find Googling it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to loop over your data and perform individual `renders` of your Handlebars file. You are currently doing that here:

```js
dataArvoresNativas.forEach((findArvoresNativas) => {
  // You should only call this once, you currently are calling it for every
  // `findArvoresNativas` you have
  res.render(/* ... */);
});
```

My guess is this accidentally isn't impacting things that much because your `find` operation is only returning one item, so your `forEach` loop only ticks through once.

So when you go to render, you are sending an Object as your `findArvNativas` variable, which you then iterate on with the built-in [`each`](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each) method. Handlebars' `each` iterates over key/value pairs in the object, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Instead, just use [dot notation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#nested-input-objects) to access the nested properties on your `findArvNativas` object.

```html
<h1>Lista de {{strArv}}</h1>

<h2>Nome: {{findArvNativas.nome}}</h2>
<h2>Nome científico: {{findArvNativas.nomecientifico}}</h2>
<h2>Ordem: {{findArvNativas.ordem}}</h2>
<h2>Origem: {{findArvNativas.origem}}</h2>
```

If you don't want to keep typing `findArvNativas` every time you want to access a property on it, you can use the [`with`](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#with) helper to set a new context.

```html
<h1>Lista de {{strArv}}</h1>

{{#with findArvNativas}}
    <h2>Nome: {{nome}}</h2>
    <h2>Nome científico: {{nomecientifico}}</h2>
    <h2>Ordem: {{ordem}}</h2>
    <h2>Origem: {{origem}}</h2>
{{/with}}
```